# How to fix Unable to add window when use Dialog in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

In my application I want use `dialog` and for this I should **set custom view** to `dialog`.
I write below codes, but when running application show me **ForceClose** error on **LogCat**.

**My Codes :**

```
   if (!isPremium) {
        count = prefsUtils.getFromShared_INT(PrefsKeys.TRIAL_COUNT.name());
        prefsUtils.setToShared_INT(PrefsKeys.TRIAL_COUNT.name(), count + 1);
        if (count > 10) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_end_trial);
            TextView dialogEndCount_premiumTxt = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogEndCount_premiumTxt);
            dialogEndCount_premiumTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
```

**Error message on LogCat :**

```
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:702)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:337)
    at com.mcc.wpnews.activity.PostDetailsActivity.initView(PostDetailsActivity.java:176)
    at com.mcc.wpnews.activity.PostDetailsActivity.onCreate(PostDetailsActivity.java:104)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6754)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know *why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`.

You cannot show a `Dialog` using the `Application`. So, replace `new Dialog(getApplicationContext())` with `new Dialog(this)`, and you should have better luck.

See [this classic blog post from Dave Smith](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) for more about when to use different types of `Context`.